# React Native Expo @azure/cosmosdb and isomorphic-webcrypto causing me headaches

Tags: react-native, azure, expo, azure-cosmosdb

Newbie React-Native Expo user and I'm getting tied up in knots with @azure/cosmosdb and the isomorphic-webcrypto dependency.  This is causing me two problems.

1. I'm getting a warning that expo-random is deprecated in favor of expo-crypto: use ExpoCrypto.getRandomBytesAsync()instead. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/

Upon further investigation it seems expo-random is used by isomorphic-webcryto.

2. I can't build my app in EAS and when I run expo doctor I get lots of problems about inconsistent version dependencies which I can't resolve.

I can't find any resolutions online and I can't fix this myself. My data is already in Azure Cosmos DB and there are other applications that are linked to this so I'm loathed to move the data elsewhere.

So what are my options?  Are there other ways to access Azure Cosmos DB without using the @azure/cosmosdb?

Answer (score 0):

Only three options here

run
`npx expo install --fix` to upgrade all dependencies to latest or recommended versions

Two, you can roll-back to expo `sdk 46` while you wait

Option 3 patch the dependency giving you issues, in your case by modifying the `isomorphic-webcryto` package to use `ExpoCrypto.getRandomBytesAsync()` test if it works then

run

```
npm i patch-package
```

And after modifying, testing and if everthing works well

run

```
npx patch-package [package-name]
```

This will create a patch folder and everything should work as intended until the package is officially updated

I have not tested this but I've patched packages before so I know patching works even in production.

Comment: Have tried to run the first option and that doesn't resolve unfortunately.

I don't think that patching isomorphic-webcrypto will resolve the build problems.  It could resolve the warning about the deprecation of expo-random but it won't stop the expo doctor warnings that are preventing build :(